# Docker Compose (TOMCAT + POSTGRES) - Spring Boot app: connection issue between containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, tomcat, spring-boot, devops

I have a spring-boot service with a connection to postgresql.The application setup works fine when I run the app with TOMCAT 9.0.6 and a docker container for postgresql (just the DB in a container).

But when I try to run the application with docker compose, it doesn't show any content.

*My docker-compose.yml*

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ./appserver
    image: webserver
    container_name: webserver
    depends_on:
      - mypostgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" 
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - front-tier
      - back-tier


  mypostgres:
    build:
      context: ./database
    image: postgresdb
    container_name: postgresdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=ggal1701
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: psql_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data 
    networks:
      - back-tier


volumes:
  psql_data:

networks:
  front-tier:
  back-tier:
```

*My dockerfile into ./database:*

```
FROM postgres:9.5

# Copy the database initialize script: 
# Contents of /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d are run on postgres startup
ADD  docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

# Default values for passwords and database name. Can be overridden on docker run
# ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw # Not defaulted for security reasons!
ENV POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
```

*My dockerfile into ./appserver:*

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.6-jre8

# tomcat-users.xml sets up user accounts for the Tomcat manager GUI
ADD tomcat/tomcat-users.xml $CATALINA_HOME/conf/

# ADD tomcat/catalina.sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/
ADD tomcat/run.sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/run.sh
RUN chmod +x $CATALINA_HOME/bin/run.sh


# create mount point for volume with application
WORKDIR $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/
COPY dos.war .
# add MySQL JDBC driver jar
ADD tomcat/postgresql-42.2.2.jar $CATALINA_HOME/lib/

# add tomcat jpda debugging environmental variables
#ENV JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
ENV JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
ENV JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"

# start tomcat8 with remote debugging
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["run.sh"]
```

*And finally, my Spring Boot configuration into an application.yml:*

```
spring:

    # Configuración de la BASE DE DATOS
    datasource:
        dataSourceClassName: org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource
        url: jdbc:postgresql://mypostgres:5432/ggal1701
        username: postgres
        password: postgres
        maximum-pool-size: 5

    application:
        url: http://webserver:8080
    profiles:
        active: prod
    devtools:
        restart:
            enabled: false
        livereload:
            enabled: false

server:
    compression:
        enabled: true
        mime-types: text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css, application/javascript, application/json
```

**I use javamelody and when I go to the path it loads it correctly.**

[image]

But in the app path it only loads the title of the page in the tab and nothing else.

Tomcat logs looks ok, except this (nothing about connection):

```
webserver     | 09:50:43.673 [main] WARN es.asd.GGAL1701.ApplicationWebXml - No Spring profile configured, running with default configuracion
webserver     | 09:50:44.466 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word]
webserver     | 09:50:44.467 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/logging.exception-conversion-word] not found - trying original name [logging.exception-conversion-word]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].
webserver     | 09:50:44.467 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate - Looking up JNDI object with name [logging.exception-conversion-word]
webserver     | 09:50:44.467 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [logging.exception-conversion-word] threw NamingException with message: Name [logging.exception-conversion-word] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [logging.exception-conversion-word].. Returning null.
```

**Any idea is welcome. The database seems to be working correctly since it works well with tomcat on localhost. But by dockerizing Tomcat, it fails.**

---

**Edit nº1**: Attempting to run it on local first, then upload it to the cloud. These failures are local.

**Edit nº2**: Some new logs from tomcat docker:

```
t ot@281078c55f64:/usr/local/tomcat/logs# cat localhost_access_log.2018-04-11.txt
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018:08:28:28 +0000] "GET /dos HTTP/1.1" 302 -
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018:08:28:28 +0000] "GET /dos/ HTTP/1.1" 200 964
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018:08:28:28 +0000] "GET /assets/css/main-c4c779892e.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1111
172.18.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2018:08:28:28 +0000] "GET /app/vendor-511f175b57.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1101


root@281078c55f64:/usr/local/tomcat/logs# cat localhost.2018-04-11.log 
11-Apr-2018 08:27:57.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 2 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.958 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.959 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.960 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: attributeAdded('StockTicker', 'async.Stockticker@267f6b32')


root@281078c55f64:/usr/local/tomcat/logs# cat catalina.2018-04-11.log  11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.581 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:  Apache Tomcat/9.0.6 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:    Mar 5 2018 09:34:35 UTC 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:  
9.0.6.0 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:         Linux 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:     
3.16.0-5-amd64 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:    amd64 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.583 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_162-8u162-b12-1~deb9u1-b12 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:      Oracle Corporation 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:
-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.16] using APR version [1.5.2]. 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true]. 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.585 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true] 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.588 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017] 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.654 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.664 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.675 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.676 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.677 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 406 ms 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina] 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.6 11-Apr-2018 08:27:54.723 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/dos.war] 11-Apr-2018 08:27:57.309 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.765 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/dos.war] has finished in [20,041] ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.767 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [199] ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:14.967 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.022 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [55] ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.022 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.075 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [53] ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.076 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.138 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [62] ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.138 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.197 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [59] ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.202 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.212 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:15.225 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 20547 ms 11-Apr-2018 08:28:25.201 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/log] 11-Apr-2018 08:28:25.256 INFO [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/log] has finished in [55] ms
```

**I also tried to pass the parameters through JAVA_OPTS, but it still doesn't show the application when I docker the tomcat.**

```
environment:
  - "JAVA_OPTS=-Ddatasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:postgresql://mypostgres:5432/ggal1701 -Ddatasource.user=postgres -Ddatasource.password=postgres"
```

**Edit nº3**: Connecting to an external database (RDS AWS) does not work either, while in local, the same version of Tomcat connects without problems. So all the trouble seems to be coming from the dockerized Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why yet, but changing the version of Tomcat has gone. It is not a question of using an earlier or later version. With Tomcat version 8 it works or not according to the selected jre, but it is also no problem with the version of the jre because trying the same one in another version does not work.

With tomcat running in localhost my application works perfectly. With docker, using the same version 9.0.6, it does not.

My current docker-compose in case someone might find it useful:

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  mytomcat:
    build:
      context: ./appserver
    image: webserver
    container_name: webserver
    hostname: webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8000:8000"
#    links:
#      - mypostgres:postgresdb
    networks:
      - main

  mypostgres:
    build:
      context: ./database
    image: postgresdb
    container_name: postgresdb
    hostname: postgresdb
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - main

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  main:
```

I don't give my answer as the solution, because I don't think it is. The solution would be that it works with the same version that it does in localhost; so alternative answers, explanations or solutions are welcome.